# Does t.test(y1, y2, paired=T) imply var.equal=T?

Tags: r

In R, does `t.test(y1, y2, paired=T)` imply `var.equal=T`?

I'm asking because that'll help me to figure out whether Welch's t-test is ever appropriate for a paired t-test.

Comment: clearly in the documentation: `If paired is TRUE then both x and y must be specified and they must be the same length. Missing values are silently removed (in pairs if paired is TRUE). If var.equal is TRUE then the pooled estimate of the variance is used. By default, if var.equal is FALSE then the variance is estimated separately for both groups and the Welch modification to the degrees of freedom is used.`

Comment: I read the part of the docs that you quote, but I wasn't sure if I could assume this to mean that I can meaningfully combine `paired=T` with both values of `var.equal`. Are you? It would seem to me that variances dependent samples would always be about equal…

Comment: Yes you can. The default is `FALSE` so if you don't give that argument, `t.test` will just use what is default (generally the defaults are listed in the "usage" part of the documentations). You have to explicitly change to `TRUE`, otherwise. If it were to change, a good r programmer would make it spit out a message or warning to tell you that the default is no longer being used. You can play around with the options and see what changes.

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding stupid. I do, in fact, generally know how to interpret command synopses. It's my ignorance of statistics that makes me question things. Do you think it would be appropriate if I were to delete my question? I don't want to needlessly pollute this site with RTFM-level questions.

Comment: @rawr No, you can't combine `paired` and `var.equal`. It doesn't make sense; see the answer below.

Comment: Julio, that is not the point. This is a programming site not a stat site. Yes you can use paired and var.equal in the call to ttest--you even did it in your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run a paired test with `x` and `y`, you're actually running a one-sample test on `d=x-y`. This means that there is only one variable `d` and therefore only one sample to get variance for.

**So it doesn't make sense to talk about `var.equal` with a paired test.**

You can see that all these three tests give you the same results.

```
> set.seed(0)             # Sample data
> x <- rnorm(50, mean=10)
> y <- x+rnorm(50)

> t.test(x,y,paired=T,var.equal=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  x and y
t = -0.1766, df = 49, p-value = 0.8605
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2649616  0.2221498
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
            -0.02140593 

> t.test(x,y,paired=T,var.equal=F)

        Paired t-test

data:  x and y
t = -0.1766, df = 49, p-value = 0.8605
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2649616  0.2221498
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
            -0.02140593 

> t.test(x-y)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x - y
t = -0.1766, df = 49, p-value = 0.8605
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2649616  0.2221498
sample estimates:
  mean of x 
-0.02140593
```

You can see details on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Calculations). There you see that Welch is only used with unpaired samples.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it very clear to me. I'd vote you up, but I don't have the requisite reputation. ;)